# Is this homogeneous polynomial the sum of the square of sums?

Tags: polynomials

The polynomial in question:

$\sum_i^6 x_i^2 + 2x_1(-x_2+x_3-x_4-x_5+x_6) \mathord{\cdot\cdot\cdot}$

$\ \ \ \ \ \ \mathord{\cdot\cdot\cdot} + 2x_2(-x_3+x_4+x_5-x_6) \mathord{\cdot\cdot\cdot}$

$\ \ \ \ \ \ \mathord{\cdot\cdot\cdot} + 2x_3(-x_4+x_5-x_6) \mathord{\cdot\cdot\cdot}$

$\ \ \ \ \ \ \mathord{\cdot\cdot\cdot} + 2x_4(-x_5+x_6) \mathord{\cdot\cdot\cdot}$

$\ \ \ \ \ \ \mathord{\cdot\cdot\cdot} + 2x_5(-x_6) \mathord{\cdot\cdot\cdot}$

$\ \ \ \ \ \ \mathord{\cdot\cdot\cdot} + 2x_6(0)$

Can this be simplified in any way? I tried to express it as the square of a sum with different sign coefficients, but If you choose the sign in front of $x_1$ then the rest of the signs are determined from the first term: $\pm,\mp,\pm,\mp,\mp,\pm$. But that doesn't agree with all the rest of the terms; some, but not all.

$(\pm x_1\mp x_2 \pm x_3 \mp x_4 \mp x_5 \pm x_6)^2 =$

$\sum_i^6 x_i^2 + 2x_1(-x_2+x_3-x_4-x_5+x_6) \mathord{\cdot\cdot\cdot}$

$\ \ \ \ \ \ \mathord{\cdot\cdot\cdot} + 2x_2(-x_3+x_4+x_5-x_6) \mathord{\cdot\cdot\cdot}$

$\ \ \ \ \ \ \mathord{\cdot\cdot\cdot} + 2x_3(-x_4-x_5+x_6) \mathord{\cdot\cdot\cdot}$

$\ \ \ \ \ \ \mathord{\cdot\cdot\cdot} + 2x_4(+x_5-x_6) \mathord{\cdot\cdot\cdot}$

$\ \ \ \ \ \ \mathord{\cdot\cdot\cdot} + 2x_5(-x_6) \mathord{\cdot\cdot\cdot}$

$\ \ \ \ \ \ \mathord{\cdot\cdot\cdot} + 2x_6(0)$

So terms $3$, and $4$ are "wrong". The signs for $x_5$ and $x_6$ "should" be exchanged. Is there anyting I'm missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The table below represents to sign of the products as a symmetric matrix. I've partitioned it into four *realizable* multiplication tables for $s_i = \pm 1$ which is the coefficient of $x_i$. Notice that If the upper left hand table for $s_1$, and $s_2$ is true, and the upper-right, and lower left tables are true then the lower right table can't be true.

$$
\begin{array}{c|cc:cccc}
\cdot & s_1 & s_2 & s_3 & s_4 & s_5 & s_6\\
\hline
s_1 & + & - & + & - & - & +\\
s_2 & - & + & - & + & + & - \\
\hdashline
s_3 & + & - & + & - & + & -\\
s_4 & - & + & - & + & - & +\\
s_5 & - & + & + & - & + & -\\
s_6 & + & - & - & + & - & +
\end{array}
$$

The partition illustrated in the table above represents the expression:

$(x_1-x_2)^2+2(x_1-x_2)(x_3-x_-x_5+x_6)+(x_3-x_4+x_5-x_6)^2$

There are many ways to partition the table, but for my purposes I wanted the terms to be positive, so I took the difference of the table realized by the first row and column, subtracted the third-through-sixth row square, then added in the lower right hand table from the original.

$$
\begin{array}{c|cccccc}
\cdot & s_1 & s_2 & s_3 & s_4 & s_5 & s_6\\
\hline
s_1 & + & - & + & - & - & +\\
s_2 & - & + & - & + & + & - \\
s_3 & + & - & + & - & + & -\\
s_4 & - & + & - & + & - & +\\
s_5 & - & + & + & - & + & -\\
s_6 & + & - & - & + & - & +
\end{array} =
$$
$$
\begin{array}{c|cccccc}
\cdot & s_1 & s_2 & s_3 & s_4 & s_5 & s_6\\
\hline
s_1 & + & - & + & - & - & +\\
s_2 & - & + & - & + & + & - \\
s_3 & + & - & + & - & - & +\\
s_4 & - & + & - & + & + & -\\
s_5 & - & + & - & + & + & -\\
s_6 & + & - & + & - & - & +
\end{array}-
\begin{array}{c|cccc}
\cdot &s_3 & s_4 & s_5 & s_6\\
\hline
s_3 &  + & - & - & +\\
s_4 &  - & + & + & -\\
s_5 &  - & + & + & -\\
s_6 &  + & - & - & +
\end{array}+
\begin{array}{c|cccc}
\cdot &s_3 & s_4 & s_5 & s_6\\
\hline
s_3 &  + & - & + & -\\
s_4 &  - & + & - & +\\
s_5 &  + & - & + & -\\
s_6 &  - & + & - & +
\end{array}
$$

So the expression is then:

$(x_1 -x_2 +x_3-x_4-x_5+x_6)^2-(x_3-x_4-x_5+x_6)^2+(x_3-x_4+x_5-x_6)^2$

Answer (score 1):

You can write it as $$(x_1-x_2+x_3-x_4-x_5+x_6)^2+4(x_3x_5-x_3x_6-x_4x_5+x_4x_6)=\\=(x_1-x_2+x_3-x_4-x_5+x_6)^2+4(x_3-x_4)(x_5-x_6)$$

Comment: Yes, you can also get the terms $4(x_1-x_2)(x_3-x_4)$, and $-4(x_1-x_2)(x_5-x_6)$ in a similar fashion. Could these sequential factors be a clue?